# Does leaving a sector early give the player more time in the next sector?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

In FTL the player can generally leave a sector before the rebel fleet makes it absolutely necessary to jump to the next sector.

Often it can be a good strategy to spend a few extra jumps in a sector gathering resources because the next sector is usually slightly more difficult.  But a player could be in a hostile sector and want to spend more jumps in the next less hostile sector.

Does leaving a sector early give the player more time in the next sector?

Or does the rebel fleet counter reset for each sector after a jump to a new sector?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No, whether or not you jump out early has no effect on the delay of the rebel fleet in the next sector, therefore its to your benefit if you visit as many locations as possible in each sector.